# Google drive on windows 7. How do I disconect

Tags: windows-7

I have just received and e-mail with a photo attachment. Somehow or another the photo has been transfered to google drive and I cannot print the photo. I have mozilla on my laptop and google drive on my iPad. How do I disconect google drive so that I can print the photos or how do I print on Google Drive?
I am not very computer literate!!

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the tray icon, and select `Quit Google Drive`. This will disconnect your computer until you relaunch the client.  Though I'm not sure how GD running would prevent you printing an image.